# Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text not found

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-mlkit

I have problem with ML Vision OCR Recognition in my Flutter app.
I got following error:
*W/DynamiteModule(22897): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.text not found.*

```
Future OCRImage(File Image)async{
    FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(Image);
    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
    VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage); // <--error shows after this

    for (TextBlock block in visionText.blocks) {

      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        for (TextElement word in line.elements) {

          text = text + word.text + ' ';

        }
        text = text + '\n';
      }
    }
    textRecognizer.close();
    //return text;
  }
```

I've tried everything but without success:( I'm not sure what is the problem.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you running it on physical device or emulator? Do you have Google play services installed on the device? If so, have you tried updating Google play services?

Also worth double checking, but it's your app communicating with the internet?

Please mention what you have tried.

Comment: I'm running on physical device. I have google play services installed. My app is not communicating with internet.

Comment: Firebase Vision OCR is deprecated by the ML Kit. You can try the new one to see if the issue exists https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android

Comment: I'm usingthis package: firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart. Still dont know what cause this issue:/

Comment: Hi, it seems that your module for running the text recognizer is not downloaded. Could you try the follow steps to see if any of these can help? 1. Update your google play service version 2. update your play store app version 3. reboot your device  If non of these helps, could you attach a bugreport and file a bug here? https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=897785&template=1457144